# mysql поиск дубликатов

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, как в MySQL можно организовать поиск дубликатов в поле?
Вывести только неповторяющиеся значения можно с помощью `DISTINCT`, а вот как можно вывести только повторяющиеся значения?

Comment: group by поле having count(1)>1

Comment: @Mike, cпасибо, это то, что было нужно!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При помощи конструкции `HAVING()`

```
SELECT fld, COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY fld HAVING(*) > 1
```